# Best way to pass user credentials to ASPx page?

Tags: asp.net, hash, webforms, credentials, sha256

I have old ASP website with default.aspx homepage.

What is the best way  to pass user login credentials ?
I was thinking about adding hashed version of email/password and append it to url, like
defaul.aspx?param=HASH

I know this is unsecure , so looking for better solution.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT:** sorry I wasnt clear enough. Hash token is generated on wordpress site. With that in mind, user is redirected to ASP.NET website with url like:
domain.com/default.aspx?param=hash

from that hash value I need to decrypet email/password and authenticate user.
Sha256 is definately not the way to do it. please provide another solutiuon..

Answer (score 0):

Form values should be fine:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="Email" placeholder="Enter email address" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="Password" TextMode="Password" placeholder="Password" />

<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

When you click the button, the form values will be "posted back" to the server, so in your code file (I'm assuming C#), you'll have an event handler that looks something like this:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var email = Email.Text;
    var password = Password.Text;
}
```

If you want to use these values on a different page, you may want to "tokenize" them and put the token in as the querystring value.

I haven't yet managed an ASPX example of how to do this, but I've got examples for generating JWT tokens in asp.net core and mvc [here](https://github.com/logan-cy/jwt-register) that you can reference.

Comment: I have reformulted question. please check